Derivation of LDA estimates for 1 dimensional case
In An Introduction to Statistical Learning Section 4.4.1, where it discusses LDA for classification, which is just a Bayes classifier with an assumption that the probability density function of each class is Gaussian and has the same variance (1D case), but in that book it does not explain how the estimates in 4.20 are obtained. From what assumptions and how do we derive these estimates?
$$
\hat \mu_k = \frac{1}{n_k} \sum_i^{n_k} x_{ik} \\[10pt]
\hat \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n-K} \sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}(x_{ik}- \hat \mu_k)^2
$$
